# Drawing fundamental domains with sage

Tags: sagemath

What is the easiest way to draw fundamental domains for congruence subgroups of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ in sage?

Answer (score 5):

An easy way is to use [FareySymbol](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/11709). You can for example define the congruence subgroup $\Gamma_1(5)$ like this:

```
G = Gamma1(5)
```

Then use this to plot a fundamental domain:

```
FareySymbol(G).fundamental_domain()
```

This yields the following image:

[image]

Comment: This helps a lot thank you! Is there a way to get a result what is symmetric in the y-axis?

Comment: @mathmarseille There might be, but I don't know how to! The only options I could find were "fill", "linestyle", "color", "show_pairing", "tesselation", "color_even", "thickness" and "ymax".